# Blazor Wasm Upload Files Hangs

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

When I try to load a binary file to server the client refresh the page in a strange way...

Setup: Asp.Net 6 with Client (Blazor wasm) and Server (Asp.Net)

Client code:

```
<InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" />


private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var file = e.File;
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), "file", file.Name);

    try
    {
        var response = await Http.PostAsync("/ModuleManager", content);

        var value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Never came here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

Server Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        // Check folder name
        using MemoryStream ms = new();
        await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        var folderName = file.FileName.Substring(0, file.FileName.IndexOf('.'));

        // Create server path
        string path = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "_content", folderName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        // Save resources
        LoadResources(bytes, path);

        return Created($"/_content/{folderName}", folderName);
    }
```

The file is loaded but the page reloads and the commented line on client method never gets hit, looking the Browser DevTools I can see this in Console:

[image]

And this in Network:

[image]

Seems like Blazor is restarting the cache serveral times and refresh the page, like a memory leak or something like that? The "catch" section is not reached either.

Comment: Can you try updating the component to something like this `<InputFile OnChange="@(async e => await OnInputFileChange(e))" />

Comment: Hello, just to understand better I have a question. Can you show us the Http service that you use, and how you inject it in the component please?

Comment: Ok, I'm injecting Http with the normal way @inject HttpClient Http;
Now I thing the problem is inside the LoadResources(bytes, path); wich opens and unzip the files (is a zip file) and the save method seems to be working in blocking mode

Comment: @DylanBarquilla is a public repo where I'm working on, you can see the full code in this address https://github.com/elgransan/BlazorPluginComponents/blob/LoadPackagedRCL/Client/Pages/ModuleManager.razor

Comment: One last comment, seems like when I write a ".css" file inside the "_content" folder Blazor get a signal of restart the app

Comment: Oh I just got a look on the Git repo, and I understand the purpose here! With your last comment I understand that you do not have any problem if you try to write other file (not .css) in _content?

I will need to give a look tomorrow, I had some issue with uploading files (and blocking ZIP for example), but code is on my PRO laptop :/

Comment: Yes, recently I tested it file by file I noticed that when I upload a css file I get the app restart, but it's not happening with another file type

Comment: I just checked the Git repo (very interesting project indeed) and I will try to correct the issue. Could you confirm me that the branch LoadPackagedRCL is the correct one to use?

Comment: I already merged the brach with the master brach, you can use that, thank you!